# loess with interaction effects

Tags: r

I have a question with regard to the `loess()` function in R. I have a situation with four main effects and I would like to also include interactions. Clearly, interactions are important in this model based on the figures and the residuals.

Is it possible to do locally smooth regression with interaction effects included?

Comment: have you tried `dd <- data.frame(z=rnorm(1000),a=rnorm(1000),b=rnorm(1000),c=rnorm(1000),d=rnorm(1000));  L1 <- loess(z~a+b+c+d,data=dd); L2 <- loess(z~(a+b+c+d)^2,data=dd)` ?  I don't know if it does something sensible/what you want, but there are no warnings or errors ...

Comment: There's also a `locfit` package,

Comment: Thanks, I was not aware if the locfit package could handle interactions. I will look into it and also Ben's suggestion.